# Difference of sha1 hashes in PHP and Node.JS for cyrillic

Tags: php, node.js, sha

If i try to get sha1 from "ABC" they are same if PHP and Node.JS.

```js
function sha1(input) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha1').update(input).digest('hex');
};
```

But if i try to take hash of something cyrillic like this: "ЭЮЯЁ" they are not.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you use the same encoding for both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is likely that the [character set/encodings aren't matching](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding).

If the string in PHP is UTF-8 encoded, you can mirror that in Node.js by specifying `'utf8'`:

```
function sha1(input) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha1').update(input, 'utf8').digest('hex');
};
```

```
> crypto.createHash('sha1').update('ЭЮЯЁ').digest('hex')
'da7f63ac9a3b5c67c8920871145cb5904f3df29a'
```

```
> crypto.createHash('sha1').update('ЭЮЯЁ', 'utf8').digest('hex')
'f78c3521413a8321231e35665f8c4a16550e182a'
```

`'ABC'` will have a better chance of matching because these are all [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters and ASCII is a starting point for many other character sets. It's when you get beyond ASCII that you'll more often run into conflicts.